# Can't run a command line prediction against a saved Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm having trouble exporting and running a simple example from the command line.  The example just trains on random numbers 0-99 and labels the values 0 if less than 50, otherwise the label is 1.  I want to be able to save the model then use it later to generate a prediction against a value entered via the command line.

[Here is the rough guide I am using for model saving and CLI](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model).

The environment is the [Tensorflow Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/).

Here is the program - it takes around 10 seconds to run in my environment.

```
"""Create a simple model that can be run from the CLI."""
import math
import os
import numpy as np
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'  # Prevents the compiler warnings
import tensorflow as tf  # pylint: disable=import-error


def generate_value_list(size=100):
    """Return an array of random values 0-99."""
    value_list = np.random.rand(size)
    value_list = [math.trunc(x * 100) for x in value_list]

    return value_list


def generate_label_list(value_list):
    """Return an array of labels for the passed values."""
    label_list = [0 if x < 50 else 1 for x in value_list]

    return label_list


def input_fn():
    """Generate input for training or evaluating."""
    value_list = generate_value_list()
    label_list = generate_label_list(value_list)
    features = {"value_list": value_list}

    return features, label_list


def main():
    """Execute the main program."""
    content = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key='value_list')
    columns = [content]
    estimator = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(
        feature_columns=columns,
        optimizer=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(
            learning_rate=0.1,
            l1_regularization_strength=0.001))

    estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=500)
    result = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn, steps=5)
    print result

    feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(columns)
    export_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
    estimator.export_savedmodel('/notebooks/model', export_input_fn)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

After running the program I have a model saved in the model directory.  To see the model interface, I run the following command:

```
saved_model_cli show --dir /notebooks/model/1505225506 --all
```

and I get this:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['None']:
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: input_example_tensor:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1, 2)
    name: linear/head/Tile:0
outputs['scores'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 2)
    name: linear/head/predictions/probabilities:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/classify

signature_def['classification']:
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: input_example_tensor:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1, 2)
    name: linear/head/Tile:0
outputs['scores'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 2)
    name: linear/head/predictions/probabilities:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/classify

signature_def['regression']:
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: input_example_tensor:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
outputs['outputs'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 1)
    name: linear/head/predictions/logistic:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/regress

signature_def['serving_default']:
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: input_example_tensor:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1, 2)
    name: linear/head/Tile:0
outputs['scores'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 2)
    name: linear/head/predictions/probabilities:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/classify
```

Next I run this to get a prediction on the number input:

```
saved_model_cli run --dir /notebooks/model/1505225506 --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default --input_exprs 'inputs=[32]'
```

and I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/saved_model_cli", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/saved_model_cli.py", line 649, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/saved_model_cli.py", line 529, in run
    args.overwrite, tf_debug=args.tf_debug)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/saved_model_cli.py", line 298, in run_saved_model_with_feed_dict
    outputs = sess.run(output_tensor_names_sorted, feed_dict=inputs_feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Unable to get element from the feed as bytes.
```

I've tried many variations for the input for the model and this one seems to get the furthest in the code before erroring out.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Is there a better way to accomplish something similar?